# Why does this factory with initialize_with cause a FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :costs_estimator do 
    ignore do 
      detailed_outcome_estimate nil
      finance_estimate { detailed_outcome_estimate.try(:finance_estimate) }
      task_estimators do 
        if detailed_outcome_estimate.present?
          [ build(:task_estimator) ]
        end
      end
     end
   end

  initialize_with do 
    new(finance_estimate, task_estimators)
  end
end
```

I built a model called costs_estimator with an initializer, and I added this above factory for it. The problem now is that when I run RSpec, other tests report an error:

```
factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:42:in `method_missing':
  undefined method `finance_estimate' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x00000009c542a8>
  (NoMethodError)...
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happening with this factory and why it affects other tests? If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Do you really want `initialize_with` to apply to all factories? If not, does it work if you move it inside the factory definition?

Comment: YES! IT WORKS MAGICALLY PERFECT! thanks. hmm but can you tell me the difference?

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer and gave one reason and one possible reason why the above might have caused your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `initialize_with` to apply only to the `:costs_estimator` factory. If so, move it inside that definition:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :costs_estimator do 
    ignore do 
      detailed_outcome_estimate nil
      finance_estimate { detailed_outcome_estimate.try(:finance_estimate) }
      task_estimators do 
        if detailed_outcome_estimate.present?
          [ build(:task_estimator) ]
        end
      end
    end

    initialize_with do 
      new(finance_estimate, task_estimators)
    end

  end    
end
```

factory_girl does allow you to define `initialize_with` at the top level, in which case it will apply to all factories, but that will definitely break factories that don't define `finance_estimate` and `task_estimators`, and it's possible that it won't even work with virtual attributes, since those are defined only in the context of a single factory.